# zend framework not setup in netbeans

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans-7

I am haveing problem to setup zend framework into netbeans.
I have assign all setting in netbeans:

> Tool>Options>PHP>Zend>
>   I have put the path of zend directory where I have extract the zend framework directory.

and >Tool>Options>PHP>General>
I have put the C:\xampp\php\php.exe in php 5 Interpreter
And give Global Include Path : 
c:\xamp\php\PEAR
and 
c:\zend\library\zend\

Also 
I have set path in environment variable for php : C:\xampp\php\php.exe
and 
in php.ini : 
include_path = ";C:\xampp\php\pear\;C:\ZendFramework-1.11.12\library;"

My configration:
Window 7
xamp1.1.2
ZendFramework-1.11.12
Netbeans 7.1

Please can any one help to me?

Comment: Is the problem that you cannot use the `zf` command line script? Or is it that Netbeans is not doing autocomplete for ZF components? Or something different?

Comment: Thanks for your help
When I go through the step which said and NB show me error like this :
=========An Error Has Occurred                         
 Could not write to file "\/.zf.ini"                                    

Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.11.12
Details for action "Create" and provider "Config"
  Config
    zf create config=========


And so that my autocomplete is still not start.
Please can you help?

Comment: Personally, I don't use zf.bat very much, but when I do, I don't do it via NB, which has always been a problem for me. So, can't really help there, sorry. ;-( For autocomplete, however, just make sure that in your NB project, under `Project > Properties > Include Path`, you add the path to the ZF lib. All should then be cool.

Comment: Thanks David for sharing your thought. After long goggling I have found the solution for the Error which I said before. We have to create ZF_HOME in Environment variable. and it's solved the issue for zend command.
ZF_HOME can any valid path of your window directory. like "D:\username"  
Hope it will useful to any body who are going from this type of issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Netbeans, `Tools > Options > PHP > Zend >` is the path to zf.bat, like: `C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\bin\zf.bat`.

Don't forget to select the *register provider button* after you change this value. This is the setting that controls how Netbeans interacts with `Zend_Tool`.

Netbeans `Global Include Path : c:\xamp\php\PEAR and c:\zend\library\zend\` the global include path in Netbeans is **only** used for Netbeans modules like for autocomplete.

You windows environment `PATH` variable needs to point to the Zend Framework **/bin** like: `C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\bin` as Windows also needs to know about `zf.bat` but really doesn't need the library location.

*php.ini* does need the location of your ZF */library* folder. Just make sure this is the *php.ini* used by Apache at a minimum. Sometimes you'll have 2 *php.ini* files: one used by Apache and one used by php cli (command line interpreter). Every server setup seems to be different as regards to where the `php.ini` files are so plz check the documentation and `phpinfo()` can probably help.

Comment: +1 for a complete list and for clearly distinguishing between NB settings to use Zend_Tool, NB settings to do autocomplete, and system PATH settings. ;-) But a question: Why does `php.ini` need to know the location of the ZF lib? Do you mean to make it part of the global PHP environment `include_path`?

Comment: @DavidWeinraub php.ini doesn't need to know about ZF but I felt it was easier in this instance to explain how to include it correctly then to explain why it really doesn't matter. I do however keep ZF on my include_path on my dev machine so I don't have to think about it.